# Проверка dll на валидность цифровой подписи

Tags: c++

Недавно нашел софт, который может перенести цифровую подпись с 1 файла на другой - signThief.
Как я могу удостовериться, что dll имеет валидную.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck

Comment: @Chorkov а open source есть?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program--verifying-the-signature-of-a-pe-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN